# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Tags: powershell-3.0

When I execute the following script from PowerShell I got that exception

`Add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser"`

But when I verify my assembly I could see multiple instances so can some one tell me what might be the issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand [this article](http://www.madwithpowershell.com/2013/10/add-type-vs-reflectionassembly-in.html) correctly, PowerShell uses a static internal table for translating names like `Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser` to fully qualified assembly names, so you probably need something like

```
Add-Type -Assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
```

or use `LoadWithPartialName()`

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser')
```

to load the assembly you want.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble as well and not even Ansgar's answer was helping. My issue was that it was failing to run `Invoke-SqlCmd` from the `SQLPS` module when running from a task scheduler. I tried both *Rundeck* and *Windows Task Scheduler*, both resulted in the same error. Running the original script directly in ISE works fine.

To fix my issue, I leveraged `Invoke-SqlCmd2` from *RamblingCookieMonster* on GitHub, as it does not rely on loading those assemblies that were failing. Ansgar's answer is valid, but may not cover all circumstances. For those other cases, try the [RamblingCookieMonster from GitHub](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1).

You can load it directly in PowerShell from GitHub by running the following command:

```
Invoke-Expression "$((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/master/Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1"))"
```